# How to pass the string value pointed by a token to an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, strsep

I'm trying to put the elements from a .csv file to a 2 dimensional array. Here is the code I've wrote so far.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 200
char* data[33][13]={0};
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
void passDataToArray()
{
    const char* fileName = "input.csv"; 
    char wordsArray[MAX_SIZE]; 
    char* wordToken; 


    FILE* inputFile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (!inputFile)
    {
        printf("error: could not parse file %s\n", fileName);
    }

    while (fgets(wordsArray, sizeof(wordsArray), inputFile))
    {
        char* duplicatedArray = strdup(wordsArray);

        while(wordToken = strsep(&duplicatedArray, ",")) {

            //printf("%s ", wordToken);
            j++;
            if(j==13){
                //printf("\n%d ", i);
                i++;
                j=0;
            }
            data[i][j]=wordToken;
        }
    }

    fclose(inputFile);
}

void printData(){
    for(i = 0; i < 33; i++) {

                for(j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                printf("%s ", data[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}

int main()
{
    passDataToArray();
    printData();
}
```

**How I can print the data without any problem but can't store them in array?**

Btw I'm getting segfault for the code above. I assume that it's probably because of this line

```
data[i][j]=wordToken;
```

**1) Am I doing sth wrong with the definitions of the variables?**

**2) What is the point of storing the pointers in an array? Obviously I'm doing that wrong as well but how that helps me to save the strings in the data?**

**3) Is it possible just passing the words as String to a 2 dimensional array?**

I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: @user3121023: I don't think that this is the issue; OP uses ` strdup(wordsArray)`

Comment: assigning to `data[i][j]` when `i` is too big is probably the issue.

Comment: Don't assume about the crash, use a debugger. And tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: there is no guarantee that `i` won't be > 33 when tokenizing the file. You should resize the array & check that boundary.

Comment: @user3121023 That points to somewhere in the newly allocated (in every loop iteration) `duplicateArray`.

Comment: Note that with `j++` at the beginning of the loop you miss to write  to `data[i][0]`

Comment: Lol you were right! the problem is boundaries... thanks a lot!